# Jira Rich Filters widgets in Dashboards: query has length limitation

Tags: jira

I am using Rich Filters in Jira. What I want is to create a Dashboard with Rich Filter Results widget. One of the fields of such a widget is JQL query used to fetch jira items. The problem is that query field has limited length - a restriction  which I have never met before in Jira. My JQL is too long to be inserted into this field. I tried to find a way to use simple filter instead of JQL but failed.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter in your jql (see [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver073/advanced-searching-fields-reference-861257219.html#Advancedsearching-fieldsreference-filterFilter)).

1. Create a filter with your long query and name it for example "myfilter"
2. In you widget type this jql: `filter = "myfilter"`